# Java Web: Detect a URL with a trailing question mark and empty query string

Tags: java, url, query-string, normalization

Is there any way I can tell if there is a trailing question mark in a URL? This would theoretically be an empty non null query string while no question mark at all would be a null query string. But either way, my web app is getting `request.getQueryString() == null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
if(url.indexOf("?")== -1){//it doesn't}
```

Comment: @Johan or even  `contains("?");`

Comment: *"`getRequestURL()`:
Reconstructs the URL the client used to make the request. The returned URL contains ..., but it **does not include query string parameters**."* See [the API Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL())

Comment: I just tried it and it did not include a question mark no matter if the query string was blank, non existent or non blank. (Java EE 1.4 on a Java EE 5 testing server)

Comment: ah... I see , Currently I can only see JavaScript, Interesting requirement , I would like to know why you want to check for `?`

Comment: I would like to redirect to clear out the question mark so it will look better and to keep from creating a unique item in either bookmarks or history.

Comment: Lets assume that user is not going add `?` in `GET` , if all your links doesn't have `?` appended then it wouldn't be the case i guess

Comment: @Jave.web it is not Javascript

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:-

```
boolean hasTrailingQuestionMark = "GET".equals(request.getMethod()) && request.getParameterNames().hasMoreElements();
```

I could be wrong, but if the request is a GET and it has parameters, then I think we can safely assume there is a trailing question mark after the URI.

**UPDATE**

I just tested the code, this approach works only if you have parameters: `http://server/bla?param=1`. However, if you have just `http://server/bla?`, this condition will fail. I don't know if you are trying to capture the latter URL signature.

Comment: Sorry, it returns false, even when I have a trailing question mark. Good idea though.

Comment: Do you have parameters after the question mark, like this: `http://server/bla?param=1` ? Or without parameters, like this: `http://server/bla?`  ?

Comment: Without parameters. I am attempting to detect when there is a trailing question mark that happens to be the only question mark in the whole URL.

Comment: I doubt you are able to achieve your goal here. A trailing `?` without parameters is equivalent to not having the `?`, thus the request API might just omit the `?` out if no parameter exists.