# Any way to detect in Django whether a request URL end with a trailing question mark "?"

Tags: django, url, get, query-string

Basically asking this question, but for Python/Django:
[Java Web: Detect a URL with a trailing question mark and empty query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878274/java-web-detect-a-url-with-a-trailing-question-mark-and-empty-query-string)

A trailing question mark can have poor influence on SEO (duplicate content). In our case, it's very hard to avoid this on the client side, so I'd like to make a redirect on the server side to the non-question-mark-trailing URL. However, I can't find a way to check in Django whether a null query string was sent.

With and without "?" appended, `request.GET` is empty. Also, neither `request.get_full_path()` nor `request.build_absolute_uri()` do contain the "?" if no GET params are in `request.GET`. URL patterns don't capture query params at all.

It would also be an option to capture and redirect this in NGINX, if anybody knows how  ...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do that in Django alone. I'm almost sure that correctly set canonical URLs should take care of indexing incorrect paths.

Comment: Thanks, that's good advice!